# PlotlyJS in Julia : xaxis setting

Tags: julia, plotly, plotly.js

#### I want to draw some points in a three-dimensional coordinate system, and make some adjustments to the range displayed by the x, y, and z axes.

For example, the range of the x-axis is set to -1~8 (but the x-coordinate range of the plotted point is only 1~2), I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
node_date = DataFrame(A = node_x,B = node_y,C = node_z)
data = scatter3d(node_date,x =:A,y =:B,z = :C,mode="markers")
layout = Layout(xaxis_range=[-1, 8])
plot(data,layout)
```

If the above code is changed to a two-dimensional figure, it is effective.
How should I modify the program now?

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.1.1
Commit 55e36cc308 (2019-05-16 04:10 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = "C:\Users\huoze\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.38.0-beta0\atom.exe"  -a
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying `scene`'s `xaxis` instead of `xaxis_range` in `Layout` with [`attr`](http://spencerlyon.com/PlotlyJS.jl/building_traces_layouts/#attr).

Instead of

```
layout = Layout(xaxis_range=[-1, 8])
```

use

```
layout = Layout(;scene=attr(;xaxis=attr(;range=[-1, 8])))
```

Inspiration: https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-axes/